# RegistryKey last write time

Tags: c#, .net

Using `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` (or any related classes), how can I query the last write time of a registry key?

Comment: You can't.  Windows doesn't track "time modified" of individual keys.

Comment: @paulsm4 Can't you with the `RegQueryInfoKey` WinAPI function? I'm trying to see if there's some native .NET method to achieve this though.

Comment: @paulsm4 That's not true. Creation times aren't stored, but last modified times are.

Comment: @paulsm4 According to the answer below you can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use P/Invoke to make a call to the Win32 API:

[MSDN: `RegQueryInfoKey` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724902%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Signature from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/RegQueryInfoKey.html):

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint="RegQueryInfoKey", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError=true)]
extern private static int RegQueryInfoKey(
    UIntPtr hkey,
    out StringBuilder lpClass,
    ref uint lpcbClass,
    IntPtr lpReserved,
    out uint lpcSubKeys,
    out uint lpcbMaxSubKeyLen,
    out uint lpcbMaxClassLen,
    out uint lpcValues,
    out uint lpcbMaxValueNameLen,
    out uint lpcbMaxValueLen,
    out uint lpcbSecurityDescriptor,
    IntPtr lpftLastWriteTime);
```